# Move MySQL table row to another table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i tried to follow this [mysql - move rows from one table to another with action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885612/mysql-move-rows-from-one-table-to-another-with-action) to perform a "move to archive" function using PDO and i am failing miserably.

So i have created a job card system, and to cut it short, when a job is complete, i have a "ARCHIVE" button that essentially needs to move the selected job card from table "repairs" into table "archived_repairs". The 2 tables are exactly the same, it just needs to be deleted from repairs table and moved to archived_repairs table in case we need to come back to it at a later stage.

This is the button/link i am using on my CRUD table:

```
<td><a href="archive_repair.php?archive_id=<?php echo $row['job_number']; ?>" name="btn_archive" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return confirm('You are about to send this Job Card to the Archive database. Please only press OK if you have invoiced this client, inserted the invoice number into ECEMS and the repair has been paid for and collected by the customer and is no longer with us....');">Archive</a></td>
```

The above is fine and dandy and goes to a page i named "archive_repair.php" with the following php code:

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";

if (isset($_REQUEST['archive_id']))
{
    try
    {
        $job_number = $_REQUEST['archive_id'];
        $select_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE job_number =:job_number');
        $select_stmt->bindParam(':job_number', $job_number);
        $select_stmt->execute();
        $row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        extract($row);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $e->getMessage();
    }

}

if (isset($_REQUEST['btn_archive']))
{

    $job_number = $_REQUEST['job_number'];
    $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
    $client_full_name = $_REQUEST['client_full_name'];
    $client_email = $_REQUEST['client_email'];
    $client_phone = $_REQUEST['client_phone'];
    $item_for_repair = $_REQUEST['item_for_repair'];
    $repair_description = $_REQUEST['repair_description'];
    $hardware_details = $_REQUEST['hardware_details'];
    $diagnostic_fee = $_REQUEST['diagnostic_fee'];
    $tech_assigned = $_REQUEST['tech_assigned'];
    $current_status = $_REQUEST['current_status'];
    $technician_notes = $_REQUEST['technician_notes'];
    $admin_notes = $_REQUEST['admin_notes'];
    $invoice_status = $_REQUEST['invoice_status'];
    $invoice_number = $_REQUEST['invoice_number'];

    if (empty($invoice_status))
    {
        $errorMsg = "Please change Invoice Status Before Archiving this Job Card";
    }
    else if (empty($invoice_number))
    {
        $errorMsg = "Please Enter a SAGE Invoice Reference Before Archiving this Job Card";
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (!isset($errorMsg))
            {
                $archive_stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO archived_repairs job_number=:job_number, date=:date, client_full_name=:client_full_name, client_email=:client_email, client_phone=:client_phone, item_for_repair=:item_for_repair, repair_description=:repair_description, hardware_details=:hardware_details, diagnostic_fee=:diagnostic_fee, tech_assigned=:tech_assigned, current_status=:current_status, technician_notes=:technician_notes, admin_notes=:admin_notes, invoice_status=:invoice_status, invoice_number=:invoice_number');
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':job_number', $job_number);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':client_full_name', $client_full_name);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':client_email', $client_email);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':client_phone', $client_phone);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':item_for_repair', $item_for_repair);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':repair_description', $repair_description);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':hardware_details', $hardware_details);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':diagnostic_fee', $diagnostic_fee);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':tech_assigned', $tech_assigned);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':current_status', $current_status);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':technician_notes', $technician_notes);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':admin_notes', $admin_notes);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':invoice_status', $invoice_status);
                $archive_stmt->bindParam(':invoice_number', $invoice_number);

                if ($archive_stmt->execute())
                {
                    $delete_stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM repairs WHERE job_number =:job_number');
                    $delete_stmt->bindParam(':job_number', $job_number);
                    $delete_stmt->execute();
                    header("refresh:1;repairs.php");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my connection.php file:

```
<?php
$db_host="localhost"; //localhost server 
$db_user="ecemscoz_ecemsapp"; //database username
$db_password="C3m3t3ry!@"; //database password   
$db_name="ecemscoz_ecemsapp"; //database name

try
{
 $db=new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_password);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
{
 $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When i click on the ARCHIVE button/link, the page is just blank (white screen), no errors show, nothing is moved to the other database and nothing is deleted. Ive only been coding PHP since 2020 so still new at this, but from my understanding this should of worked... Am i missing something in my code that i am not seeing?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but doesn't `$job_number = $_REQUEST['job_number'];` need to come *before* the query?

Comment: WSOD (White Screen of Death). Check the server error log to find the details.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have a much easier time doing this directly in MySQL.

Something like the following should be essentially all you need.

```php
$archive_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO archived_repairs (
    job_number,
    date,
    client_full_name,
    client_email,
    client_phone,
    item_for_repair,
    repair_description,
    hardware_details,
    diagnostic_fee,
    tech_assigned,
    current_status,
    technician_notes,
    admin_notes,
    invoice_status,
    invoice_number
) (
    SELECT
        job_number,
        date,
        client_full_name,
        client_email,
        client_phone,
        item_for_repair,
        repair_description,
        hardware_details,
        diagnostic_fee,
        tech_assigned,
        current_status,
        technician_notes,
        admin_notes,
        invoice_status,
        invoice_number 
    FROM
        repairs 
    WHERE
    job_number =:job_number )");
$archive_stmt->bindParam(':job_number', $job_number);

if ($archive_stmt->execute())
{
    $delete_stmt = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM repairs WHERE job_number =:job_number');
    $delete_stmt->bindParam(':job_number', $job_number);
    $delete_stmt->execute();
    header("refresh:1;repairs.php");
}
```

Comment: Explicitly listing fields is also safer than trying to use the SO answers that used wildcards in case you do ever modify one or both tables.  In one logging table at work I copy all fields, but the log table has a couple of extra fields including a timestamp for when the entry was added and the login/user that made the change,

Comment: Yup, to @DaveS 's point `*` is tempting but more danger than it's worth, particularly in production code.

Comment: @donatJ You are a rock star. I have learned a lot from your answer and i thank you so much for your contribution!